# My execution remains blocked on Configuring > 3/4 projects react native project

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, sdk, execution

Please I have a soutenance I have to solve the problem,
My execution remains blocked on Configuring > 3/4 projects
[image]

[image]

package.json